# MSI package without UAC administrative privileges

Tags: windows-installer

I want to install an outlook add-in for a user who does not have administrative privileges. I used MsiInfo.exe myAddIn.msi -W 8 to author package without the UAC dialog box. It does not ask for the admin privileges but during the installation it gives error stating that one of my  mycustomxyz.dll not found.

When i change the word count to 2, it works perfectly but asks for the administrator privileges.

I am using VS team system 2008 on windows 7 (64 bit). Is there any workaround for this.

Br,

Comment: i managed to solve it with command

MsiInfo myAddIn.msi -W 10

Comment: Why not adding your comment above as an actual answer since it solved your problem? This way this question could be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to solve it with command MsiInfo myAddIn.msi -W 10